# MySQL Timestamp when update a specific column with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to put a timestamp when a specific column is updated.

**For example:**

```
column1: a value

dateColumn1: date column1 was updated


column2 : a value

dateColumn2: date column2 was updated
```

I use the function `getTimestamp()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone advise me on how to do this in PHP and MYSQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this only in the database, you could write a trigger that checks your conditions and updates specific timestamps if needed. But I'm assuming you don't want to fiddle around with triggers. Triggers have an advantage though: you can access the old and the new values of a row without having to write any php code.

Anyway, in case you need it here is some example code for a trigger (SQL, beware):

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Table1_UpdateTrigger $$
CREATE TRIGGER Table1_UpdateTrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON Table1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.column1 != NEW.column1 THEN
     SET NEW.dateColumn1 = NOW();
    END IF;
    IF OLD.column2 != NEW.column2 THEN
     SET NEW.dateColumn2 = NOW();
    END IF;
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Substite Table1 with your real table names, column1, etc. with real column names.

The other way is to compare the old and the new values in php. E.g. do a query fetching the old data, compare the fields you want to check, and then do one update query per field that has changed to set the new timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table
SET column1='new value', timestampcolumn=NOW()
WHERE ...
```

is one way. If you don't mind the timestamp changing anytime anything in the record is updated, then use the native "timestamp" field type, which'll update itself to "now" when the record's inserted or changed.

Comment: In relation to this it probably wouldn't hurt to take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html if you plan to use the timestamp field type.

Comment: So I can't use the Timestamp field type, I have to use Datetime right?

Comment: Yes, TIMESTAMP will overwrite the field on ANY update of the row. Use DATETIME if you want to control that yourself.

Comment: @crashdOwn it will only automatically update if you set it to do that. but if you only want manual control, DATETIME is the way to go.

Comment: You can override the timestamp field updating itself by making it part of the update... `UPDATED ... SET timestampfield=timestampfield ...`, but then you're in the same boat as using the ...=NOW() method - having to manually adjust the query based on if it's changing the field you want timestamped or not.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed it to datetime. I am assuming that later dates are greater than earlier dates. I have to sort the table by those dates. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Yes. ordering on a date/time column will work logically. ASC means older dates first, DESC means older dates last.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the MySQL function NOW(), like so:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column2 = value, dateColumn2 = NOW() WHERE somethingsomething
```

Comment: Does the column have to be DATETIME or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional statement. For example in the following trigger the 'password changed time' will be updated only when there is change in password column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_password 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF OLD.password <> NEW.password THEN
    SET NEW.password_changed_on = NOW();
    END IF;
    END //
```